# How to pass captcha while scraping amazon website

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, captcha

I am trying to scrape some basic data from amazon via python. Everything works great but I can not pass captcha control in most of cases.

I tried to wait longer with sleep function but it doesn't work. 
Is there any way to work around captcha control?

```
........

   def parse(url):
       headers = {
           'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36'
    }

    try:
        # Retrying for failed requests
        for i in range(40):
            # Generating random delays
            sleep(randint(1,10))
            # Adding verify=False to avold ssl related issues
            response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)

            if response.status_code == 200:
                doc = html.fromstring(response.content)
                XPATH_NAME = '//h1[@id="title"]//text()'
                XPATH_SALE_PRICE = '//span[contains(@id,"ourprice") or contains(@id,"saleprice")]/text()'
                XPATH_ORIGINAL_PRICE = '//td[contains(text(),"List Price") or contains(text(),"M.R.P") or contains(text(),"Price")]/following-sibling::td/text()'
                XPATH_CATEGORY = '//a[@class="a-link-normal a-color-tertiary"]//text()'
                XPATH_AVAILABILITY = '//div[@id="availability"]//text()'

                RAW_NAME = doc.xpath(XPATH_NAME)
                RAW_SALE_PRICE = doc.xpath(XPATH_SALE_PRICE)
                RAW_CATEGORY = doc.xpath(XPATH_CATEGORY)
                RAW_ORIGINAL_PRICE = doc.xpath(XPATH_ORIGINAL_PRICE)
                RAw_AVAILABILITY = doc.xpath(XPATH_AVAILABILITY)

                NAME = ' '.join(''.join(RAW_NAME).split()) if RAW_NAME else None
                SALE_PRICE = ' '.join(''.join(RAW_SALE_PRICE).split()).strip() if RAW_SALE_PRICE else None
                CATEGORY = ' > '.join([i.strip() for i in RAW_CATEGORY]) if RAW_CATEGORY else None
                ORIGINAL_PRICE = ''.join(RAW_ORIGINAL_PRICE).strip() if RAW_ORIGINAL_PRICE else None
                AVAILABILITY = ''.join(RAw_AVAILABILITY).strip() if RAw_AVAILABILITY else None

                if not ORIGINAL_PRICE:
                    ORIGINAL_PRICE = SALE_PRICE
                # retrying in case of captcha
                if not NAME:
                    raise ValueError('captcha')
                data = {
                    'NAME': NAME,
                    'SALE_PRICE': SALE_PRICE,
                    'CATEGORY': CATEGORY,
                    'ORIGINAL_PRICE': ORIGINAL_PRICE,
                    'AVAILABILITY': AVAILABILITY,
                    'URL': url,
                }
                return data
            elif response.status_code==404:
                break
    except Exception as e:
        print (e)
    def ReadAsin():
       ..........
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [strategy to defeat CAPTCHA bypass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352450/strategy-to-defeat-captcha-bypass)